# Android animation works only first time

Tags: android, animation

I wrote these lines of code to have a crossfading animation between an ImageButton (butMat) and an ImageView (imgOkMater). The animation is launched in the method OnActivityResult.
When the animation is launched the first time all it's right, the ImageButton disappears, the image appears, and after the delay set, the ImageButton reappears and the image disappears.
But when the animation is called the second time the ImageButton never disappears while the ImageView appears and then disappears correctly.

I can't figure out why.... (?!)

Code:

```
                    butMat.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(250).setStartDelay(500);
                imgOkMater.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(250).setStartDelay(500).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        imgOkMater.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(250).setStartDelay(750);
                        butMat.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(250).setStartDelay(750);
                    }
                });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try in `onAnimationEnd()` method set imagebutton Visibility to invisible or gone Like:

```
imageButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

or

```
imageButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Then again while starting animation make it

```
imageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```